# Having lists from database shown in an edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I have for example, a `User` and `Country`, a user is a part of 1 country by the countryId. In the view when editing the user, I need to select a country. How do I setup my viewModel to take a list from the database?

For eg.

**UserEditViewModel**

```
public class UserEditViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required."),
    Display(Name="Country")]
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I setup my view model to accomodate a list from the server?

**Controller Action**

```
    public ActionResult GettingStarted()
    {
        var countries = geoService.GetCountries();//What do I do with this?
        UserEditViewModel model = new UserEditViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)                
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    }
```

How do I setup the view also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this question [Asp.Net MVC Handle Drop Down Boxes that are not part of the Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881215/asp-net-mvc-handle-drop-down-boxes-that-are-not-part-of-the-model)